# How to make javascipt tabs work with html/css website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm doing work for a client and I ran into a pickle. He wanted a tab system whereby when the client clicks on the tab it opens content. Easy enough to do and I did it, however I encountered an issue. When you try to click the button to close it doesn't close for me, although it does open the new tab if clicked.

HERE is an example of the code on codepen: https://codepen.io/ghostcrawl3r/pen/vYybmJL

This is my html code:

```
<div className="tab">
    <ul style="
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        ">
        <li><a class="tablinks" onclick="menuToggle(globalToggle, event, 'sandTesting')">THE SANDSTONE TESTING</a></li>
        <li><h4>|</h4></li>
        <li><a class="tablinks" onclick="menuToggle(globalToggle, event, 'cleaningCons')">THE CLEANING CONSIDERATIONS</a></li>
        <li><h4>|</h4></li>
        <li><a class="tablinks" onclick="menuToggle(globalToggle, event, 'codePrac')">THE CODE OF PRACTICE</a></li>
    </ul>
```

```
<div id="sandTesting" class="tabcontent">
    [elementor-template id="432"]
</div>

<div id="cleaningCons" class="tabcontent">
    [elementor-template id="434"]
</div>

<div id="codePrac" class="tabcontent">
   [elementor-template id="436"]
</div>
```

and this is my Javascript:

```
   var globalToggle = false;

function menuToggle(tgl, evt, linkName){
    var state = tgl;
    tgl = !state;
    
    if(tgl) {
        globalToggle = false;
        return openCity(evt, linkName);
    } else {
        globalToggle = true;
        return document.getElementById(linkName).style.display = "none";
    }
}

function openCity(evt, linkName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(linkName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

I'm not entirely sure how to fix this. I tried to separate the globalVairable into 3 different vars and with if statements BUT when I did that to click on another tab you had to click twice.
I'd really appreciate some help as this has been plaguing me for days!

Comment: Can you create a [mre] please?

Comment: Sorry @ChrisG I forgot to add: https://codepen.io/ghostcrawl3r/pen/vYybmJL

Comment: _When you try to click the button to close it doesn't close for me._ What do you mean by this?  I don't see a close button on your code pen.  Are you wanting to be able to use the same button you clicked to open the "tab" as a sort of toggle so you can click it again to remove the "tab"?

Comment: Have you considered adding a "home" tab? That way you just return to an empty tab, instead of closing an opened one (needing to check where you are and then closing if you click the same that's currently open). Just a suggestion.

Comment: @AlexanderNied - Apologies. The functionality should be I click on Location and it shows a dropdown of content inside a tab below it. And if I should click Location again it would close the tab

Comment: @Leo I did want to make it this way but sadly I've been asked to do it like this :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    function menuToggle(tgl, evt, linkName) {
      if (!evt.target.classList.contains("active")) {
        return openCity(evt, linkName);
      } else {
        evt.target.classList.remove("active")
        return document.getElementById(linkName).style.display = "none";
      }
    }
```

You've tangled up with the toggle-logic. I would refer to a class attribute and not to a JS-variable. If you don't want to use classList you must rewrite a bit, but the logic stays the same.